# Error when trying to compile

Tags: ms-access

I'm getting a compile error:

`Sub or function not defined`(error area in bold)

Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub cboDates_AfterUpdate()
On Error Resume Next

```
Dim strInterval As String
Dim dblValue As Double
Dim datStartDate As Date
Dim datEndDate As Date
Dim WeekdayStsrt As Integer

WeekdayStsrt = 1 'Start day of week - 1=Sunday, 2=Monday, 3=Tuesday...
```

'Sets Start and End Date textboxes based on combobox selection
    strInterval = Me.cboDates.Column(1)
    dblValue = Me.cboDates.Column(2)

```
Select Case strInterval
    Case "d"
        datStartDate = Date
        datEndDate = Date
    Case "ww"
        datStartDate = Date - Weekday(Date) + WeekdayStsrt
        datEndDate = datStartDate + 6
    Case "m"
        datStartDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + dblValue, 1)
        datEndDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + dblValue + 1, 0)
        dblValue = 0
    Case "yyyy"
        datStartDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), 1, 1)
        datEndDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), 12, 31)
    Case "YTD"
        datStartDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), 1, 1)
        datEndDate = Date
        strInterval = "yyyy"
    Case "All"
        datStartDate = DateSerial(2000, 1, 1) 'Earliest Date of available data in system
        datEndDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), 12, 31)
        strInterval = "d"
End Select

Me.txtStartDate = DateAdd(strInterval, dblValue, datStartDate)
Me.txtEndDate = DateAdd(strInterval, dblValue, datEndDate)
```

End Sub
Private Sub cboReportGroup_AfterUpdate()
On Error GoTo Err_Trap
'Filter listbox based on Report Group combobox selection.

```
Dim SQL As String

Me.lstReport = Null
SQL = Me.lstReport.Tag
If Not Me.cboReportGroup = "(All)" Then
    SQL = SQL & " WHERE ReportGroup='" & Me.cboReportGroup & "'"
End If
SQL = SQL & " ORDER BY tsysReports.ReportTitle;"

Me.lstReport.RowSource = SQL
```

Err_Trap_Exit:
    Exit Sub

Err_Trap:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Err_Trap_Exit

End Sub
Private Sub cmdEndDate_Click()
On Error Resume Next
'Launch Calendar Control

```
DateCheck_MEI Me.txtEndDate
Me.cboDates = Null
```

End Sub
Private Sub cmdExport_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Trap

```
Dim SQL As String

Echo False
Call cmdOpen_Click 'execute the button that opens the report for print preview
SQLEdit_MEI "ArrivalTimingTableQuery", Application.Reports(Me.lstReport).RecordSource

If Application.Reports(Me.lstReport).Filter = "" Then
    SQL = "SELECT * FROM ArrivalTimingTableQuery "
Else
    SQL = "SELECT * FROM ArrivalTimingTableQuery WHERE " & Application.Reports(Me.lstReport).Filter
End If

SQLEdit_MEI "qryTempExport", SQL
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "qryTempExport", acFormatXLS, CurrentProject.Path & "\temp.xls", True
DoCmd.Close acReport, Me.lstReport, acSaveNo
Echo True
```

Err_Trap_Exit:
    Exit Sub

Err_Trap:
    Echo True
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Err_Trap_Exit

End Sub
Private Sub cmdOpen_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Trap

```
Dim strCriteria As String

If Me.txtEndDate < Me.txtStartDate Then
    MsgBox "End Date cannot be prior to Start Date."
    Exit Sub
End If

If IsNull(Me.lstReport) Then
    MsgBox "Please select a report"
    Exit Sub
End If

If Not Me.lstReport.Column(2) = "" Then
    strCriteria = Me.cboField & " Between #" & Me.txtStartDate & "# And #" & Me.txtEndDate & "#"
End If

DoCmd.OpenReport Me.lstReport, acViewReport, , strCriteria
```

Err_Trap_Exit:
    Exit Sub

Err_Trap:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Err_Trap_Exit

End Sub
**Private Sub cmdStartDate_Click()**
On Error Resume Next
'Launch Calendar Control
    DateCheck_MEI Me.txtStartDate
    Me.cboDates = Null

End Sub
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Call cboReportGroup_AfterUpdate
End Sub
Private Sub lstReport_Click()
On Error Resume Next

```
Me.lblDescription.Caption = "Report Description: " & Me.lstReport.Column(3)
Me.cboField.RowSource = Me.lstReport.Column(2) 'Set to values of DateCriteria field of table tsysReports
Me.cboField = Me.cboField.ItemData(0) 'Select 1st item in combobox
```

'Hide Report Criteria Section if no Date Filter for selected report
    If Me.lstReport.Column(2) = "" Then
        Me.box1.Visible = True
    Else
        Me.box1.Visible = False
    End If

End Sub
Private Sub lstReport_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
    Call cmdOpen_Click
End Sub

Comment: Can you post all of the code in that procedure please.

Comment: It has been updated with all. Thanks. appreciate your help

Comment: This is where error comes!!!

Private Sub cmdStartDate_Click() 
On Error Resume Next 'Launch Calendar Control DateCheck_MEI Me.txtStartDate Me.cboDates = Null

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

From what you've posted, and ignoring what may be wrong inside of your sub,

the fix would be to end the sub:

```
Private Sub cmdStartDate_Click()
'Do stuff
End Sub 'This is the part you are missing
```